# Whare can I find the number of mail ballot drop-off locations by county for the 2020 election?

Tags: united-states, election, data-sources

I am looking for information on the number of mail ballot drop-off places, ideally by county (or other geography), for the current election. [This document](https://healthyelections.org/sites/default/files/2020-10/Ballot_Drop_Off_0.pdf) contains information about the existence or not of such places at the state level (data is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kcRQsME9ksA0RIO1zZ7aZ0FTpauXHH9W5LFJVv1j618/edit#gid=0)). I want something more finer: number of places, by county. For instance, the graph below by [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/live/2020/nov/02/us-election-2020-live-updates-president-donald-trump-joe-biden-kamala-harris-latest-news-update?page=with:block-5fa007428f08c96f53e46a51#block-5fa007428f08c96f53e46a51) (UK newspaper) was produced with such data for two counties:

[image]

I've searched all over without success. The closest possible are some drop-off location search tool (e.g. [here](https://www.vote.org/dropbox-locator/) and [here](https://www.votinginfoproject.org/projects)), which suggest they do have the data. Unfortunately, it is not available to bulk download.

Does someone know where can I find such data?

Comment: It's likely that they'll have gotten the data from each of the 50 state boards of elections separately.

Comment: The Voter Information Project definitely has that info (see the [spec](https://github.com/votinginfoproject/vip-specification/blob/vip52/docs/built_rst/csv/elements/polling_location.rst)) but I don't see a place on the repo to download the raw data. You should be able to use their API to query it

Comment: @divibisan Interesting! structured_zip and is_drop_box seem to be what I'm looking for. Will see if that is indeed the case. Thanks!

Comment: Note that there are five counties in the state of Rhode Island, so the example graphics do not quite match the request in the question--that's a comparison of a county in Texas with the entire state of Rhode Island.

Comment: @user4556274 Yes, it's comparing a county with 4.7 million people to a state with 1.1 million people.  Regardless the number of counties, if we go by population, the comparison is *even worse* than when comparing land area.

Comment: Texas has only one drop box per county due to a mandate by the governor. BTW, while Harris County is indeed the Texas county with the highest population, Brewster County is much larger in terms of area, over five times the size of Rhode Island. To make matters worse, Brewster County has no freeways.

Comment: @divibisan They don't seem to have an API. [Google](https://developers.google.com/civic-information) has one that extracts some data from VIP, but queries are very limited.